# Laravel Spark Use Case

Tags: laravel

I have a project where Laravel Spark feels like the perfect starting point.

I have searched Google for some examples of use cases but as yet have not found any so thought I would ask here.

I am at the planning phase and putting together the development timetable.

The project has different types of users and payment plans. Payments to be taken via Stripe.

There are single users and Agency users.  The difference is that a single user finds the site and signs up in the normal credit card way.  Agencies pre buy a block of licenses from the company and then log in to the Dashboard to add users as they sell their allocation.

So my questions are.  Out of the box in Spark can:

1. I create Single User plans for 1, 3, 6 and 12 months out of the box in Spark?
2. an Agency owner log in and see their own dashboard with the number of remaining licenses that they can allocate to new users?
3. When an Agency signs up a user they do not need to pay anything as they have prepaid but I do need their number of available licenses to reduce each time.

The service can be offered in different languages so I need a way of being able to specify the following:

eg:

a) Single User on a 3, 6 or 12 months license in English.

b) Single User on 3, 6 or 12 month license in Dutch etc. (Many languages available)

c) An Agency User on a 3, 6 or 12 month license in a specific language.

Finally, there already exists a single page website for his project and I would like the base url for **non** logged in users to be this page. It is built using Bootstrap 4 and I am assuming that this is easy in Spark.

As I mentioned I am at the planning phase and am attempting to assess how much of the above can be handled out of the box by Spark and how much will be bespoke.

I hope to get my hands of Spark tomorrow but am hoping existing Spark users can advise me.

Thank you.